# how-to-update-parent-document-only-in-couchbase

Tags: couchbase, sql++

any one can help me about this query how can  Parent-document update using couchbase N1ql query

```
{
    "created_at": "2020-03-26T15:50:12.318Z",

    "created_by": 1,
    "deleted_at": "",
    "frm21_submit": null,
    "id": "6cb51519-7c6b-499d-8a8d-3c85658605fc",
    "machine_category_id": [
        "7a2eb767-faca-4762-b65b-2db9e1992c82",
        "259a4bcc-feb5-4d98-88c5-b331316e19be"
    ],

    "main_parts": [

        {
            "data": {
                "deleted_at": "777",
                "frm21_submit": null,
                "manufacturing_date": "03/31/2020",
                "model": "234234234",
                "photo": null,
                "serial_number": "324324234",
                "updated_at": "2020-03-31T14:11:48.909Z"
            },
            "id": "66354d7c-4769-4f3b-914e-bb841191e323"
        }
    ]

}
```

i want to update  parent-document only  all field are dynamic i can not selected field.
like

```
update machine set "created_by"= 1, "machine_category_id"= [
    "7a2eb767-faca-4762-b65b-2db9e1992c82",
    "259a4bcc-feb5-4d98-88c5-b331316e19be"
  ]  Where id=1
```

how to dynamically update parent document only with safe child or sub  document nothing lose data.

```
{

    "created_at": "2020-03-26T15:50:12.318Z",

    "created_by": 1,

    "deleted_at": "",

    "frm21_submit": null,

    "id": "6cb51519-7c6b-499d-8a8d-3c85658605fc",

    "machine_category_id": [
        "7a2eb767-faca-4762-b65b-2db9e1992c82",
        "259a4bcc-feb5-4d98-88c5-b331316e19be"
    ]

}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem. Why doesn't an `UPDATE` work for you?

Comment: in full document have  many more sub document but i want  update parent document
only . but i have a one problem field are not static so i can not write update query with static field so is it possible . thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear. In JOSN you can store value in field. If you don't know field how do you modify the value. If you want to overwrite/add fields on top use  UPDATE default AS d  SET d = OBJECT_CONCAT(d, {"created_by": 2,"newfiled":"xyz") WHERE .....; This overwrite field if exist and if not it adds.

Comment: Thank you so much. its working and problem solved

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your update is that it is referring to an attribute called "id" which I guess that is the key of the document. To access the document id you have to call `meta().id`

```
update default set created_by= 1, machine_category_id= [
"machine",
"asdasd"
]  Where meta().id = "1"
```

Note that the document id is a string.

Comment: hello i know meta always string , actually question is how to update dynamically
because i can not know field name and also can not use upsert. but now problem is solve as per above comment if any others solution please reply.  Thank you for your response.

Comment: Could you please update your question with the code? It is a little but unclear what you are trying to accomplish.